# J2ME Army Knife

Tags: java, image, image-processing, masking

I would like to make use of the `J2ME Army Knife` in my project.

http://www.j2mearmyknife.com/

I am mainly interested in Image Masking.
But you see the library is no longer available for download.
Is there anyone out there who has the library or knows how to do image masking in J2ME?

I am on a super tight schedule now

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to contact the author using the link provided on the site.

I'd also be careful giving / getting a copy of this software to / from someone else.  At a minimum, you should first reading the license agreement terms in detail:

http://www.j2mearmyknife.com/legal-agreement/

And, since this is a non-standard license, you'd be advised to talk to a lawyer to make sure that your layman's understanding of what it means is actually correct.